# Recursive function that gives the number of hashes present in a Merkle Mountain Range proof

Tags: performance, recursion, bitwise, solidity

I have written a function that gives the number of hashes present in a Merkle Mountain Range proof. Using Solidity, this function can be written as:

```solidity
function getMmrProofSize(uint32 index, uint32 n) private pure returns (uint8) {
    // if n is a power of 2
    if (n & (n - 1) == 0) {
        return ceiledLog2(n);
    }
    
    uint8 ceiledLog2n = ceiledLog2(n);
    uint32 shift = uint32(1 << (ceiledLog2n - 1));
        
    if (index < shift) {
        return ceiledLog2n;
    }
        
    return 1 + getMmrProofSize(index - shift, n - shift);
}
```

with `ceiledLog2` being a function that computes the ceil of the base 2 logarithm of an `uint`.

This code works as intended, but I was wondering whether it was possible to improve it.

Comment: Please find where questions about mechanisms are [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-sites-do-i-post-on)

Comment: I wish I knew value and meaning of `index` in "the outer call".

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not appear to be a code review request.

Comment: Please use a `language tag` to identify the language of the question. While you state the code is working as expected, it seems that you are asking us to rewrite the current code which is off-topic for the Code Review Community and may be off-topic for all Stack Exchange communities.

Comment: @pacmaninbw Mb, I've read the tour and thought the question was on-topic :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function returns a `ceiledLog2` of an eventual `n`, *plus* the number of times it has been called until it reaches that eventual `n`. This observation leads to a simple iterative rewrite (please pardon my [c](/questions/tagged/c)):

```
uint8_t getMmrProofSize(uint32_t index, uint32_t n)
{
    uint8_t ncalls = 0;

    uint8_t ceiledLog2n = ceiledLog2(n);
    uint32_t shift = 1 << (ceiledLog2n - 1);

    while (((n & (n-1)) != 0) && (index >= shift)) {
        ncalls += 1;
        index -= shift;
        n -= shift;
        ceiledLog2n = ceiledLog2(n);
        shift = 1 << (ceiledLog2n - 1);
    }
        
    return ncalls + ceiledLog2n;
}
```

Now, an obvious bottleneck is `ceiledLog2`. It has more or less efficient portable implementations using [bit twiddles](https://graphics.stanford.edu/%7Eseander/bithacks.html#IntegerLogObvious); for utter performance you may want to explore built-ins your DE provides.

Comment: (With both `ceiledLog2n` and `shift` computed, isn't `n` a power of two exactly when it equals `shift+shift`?)